# Directly show colored borders of referenced cells when entering a cell in MS Excel 2003

Tags: excel-2003, excel-2010

Is it possible to directly show the show colored borders of referenced cells when entering a cell in MS Excel 2003 (2010?)?.
I mean the borders you get when pressing "F2" on a cell or when clicking in the cell-edit-box above the sheet. I want them displayed every time I select a cell, not after entering edit-mode.

Thanks in advance,
Blama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' hide existing arrows
ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
' show precedents for selected range
Target.ShowPrecedents

End Sub
```

This will show the precedents for a given cell, whenever you select it.

Select a cell with a formula in it:

[image: show precedents]

Then select another cell with a formula:

[image: show precedents]